# use foreach() instead of while() with a query result

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I had this code working (I thought).

```
$sql = "SELECT
          order.id,
          order.date
        FROM
          order";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

foreach($rows as $row){
  echo $row['id'].": ".$row['date']."<br>";
}
```

The result was the same as if I would use:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo $row['id'].": ".$row['date']."<br>";
}
```

But strangely, today it stopped working. Or it never has, but then I'm getting a little crazy.

I want to use foreach() because the array $rows can also be 'manually' filled and not from a query.

What am I doing wrong..?

Comment: You can't `foreach` here. It has never worked. You've only ever fetched a single row and iterated over the *columns* in that row with `foreach`.

Comment: first one fetch 1 record only, then loops through the records columns

Comment: Why don't you use print_r($rows) before any loop and check what is actually there? You'll have a clear idea of what is going on ;)

Comment: The two results can't be same unless you have only one entry in your database. Someone deleted that entry perhaps.

Comment: Thanx all! I have my answer, see answer of DaveRandom [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15500980/2153795) below. I think I need a holiday... I really thought I had it working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has never worked (properly). `mysql_fetch_assoc()` only returns one row, your `foreach` is just iterating the columns of the first row from the result set.

You cannot use `foreach` without first using a `while` (or `for`) loop to fetch the result rows into an array.

If you want to use `foreach`, as you say, do this:

```
 $rows = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $rows[] = $row;
 }

 foreach ($rows as $row) {
     // ...
 }
```

Also, [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks Dave, this is the answer! I don't understand why I think that this code has worked.. probably I need a holiday! I also know that `mysql_` is deprecated in php 5.5. At the moment I'm making little modifications with the old `mysql_`, later I will update the whole site with `mysqli_`.

Comment: @Timo002 Btw, if you were using PDO the foreach code would actually work :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's worth knowing that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated; it is recommended not to use them any more, and switch your code to either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Now, to answer your question:

You can't use `foreach` with recordsets returned by the `mysql_xxx()` functions. It simply can't be done.

However, both of the alternative APIs (`mysqli` and `PDO`) return their recordset objects as iterators, which means you *can* use `foreach` to loop over them.

So the answer to your question is: if you want to use `foreach` to loop through a record set, you need to switch to one of the other database APIs.

(as a bonus, if you do switch, the other APIs also provide quite a bit of extra functionality over the old `mysql_xx()` functions)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` reads only single row.

That means `foreach` iterated over columns of a single row.

Comment: The two ways were never the same even though you had a single line in your DB.